# How do I use AJAX to upload file

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, file-upload

I want to use AJAX to upload.

This is my HTML code

```html
<form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload">
    File Name：<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```js
var file = document.querySelector("[type=file]").files[0], 
    reader = new FileReader; 

reader.onload = function(e){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    xhr.open("POST", document.querySelector("form#upload-form").action, true);

    //set payload
    var boundary = '------multipartformboundary' + (new Date).getTime().toString(16);
    var dashdash = '--';
    var crlf = '\r\n';

    var payload = '';
    payload += boundary;
    payload += crlf;

    payload += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"';
    payload += crlf;    

    payload += 'Content-Type: ' + file.type;
    if (file.fileName) {
        payload += '; filename="' + file.name + '"';
    }
    payload += crlf + crlf;

    payload += reader.result;
    payload += crlf;


    payload += boundary;
    payload += crlf;
    payload += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"';
    payload += crlf + crlf;
    payload += document.querySelector("[name=name]").value || ""
    payload += crlf;

    payload += boundary;
    payload += dashdash;

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary)
    xhr.send(payload)
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
```

The payload of the request looks like:

```
------multipartformboundary14e6631b3eb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG


(some binary code)
------multipartformboundary14e6631b3eb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

My test file
------multipartformboundary14e6631b3eb--
```

However, the request status is **400**.

The description says "request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." (Server is Servlet + Tomcat 8)

When I just submit the form without AJAX, it can upload successfully. Therefore, I do not think it is the server's issue.

Comment: Enable CROS (Cross-origin resource sharing) on server & Increase post body size .

Comment: You can have this a lot easier using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object) …

Comment: @Vishnu  Why should I enable CROS? The page I send request to is in the same server. Also, since I will get error even if I send a small file, such as a text/plain file, I do not think body size is the reason.

Comment: @Shiyou you are correct. i thought you may use subdomain or something to post data. and one more thing. var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest need to be var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: @Vishnu without `();` is ok.

Comment: @Shiyou i think you have to xhr.setRequestHeader before Open the request.

Comment: You may try to send it using telnet or any other web client and see if it works. ( Remember to calculate and add a Content-length )

Comment: @Vishnu If i set header before open, it will shows me error `Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.`

Answer (score 0):

In the content-type line:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary)
```

Your code provide:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=------xxxxxxxxx
```

But, it should be:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=----xxxxxxxxx
```

Notice the number of dash.

So change it to:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary.substr(2))
```

And try again.

Comment: I changed Content-type as you said ( `multipart/form-data; boundary=----multipartformboundary14e6654eec2` ). However, it still gives me 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

```
                var Self = this;
                    Self.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    Self.url = "./connect.php"; // your file to post data
                    Self.xhr.open("POST",Self.url,true);
                    Self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    Self.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(Self.xhr.readyState == 4 && Self.xhr.status == 200) {
                    Self.return_data = Self.xhr.responseText.trim();

                    }
              Self.xhr.send(Self.logData);
```

This is how i POST data to my server using XHR request. and connect.php will update my Database. so you can add what ever the data you need to send to "Self.logData" before making XHR request. and **you need a file like connect.php or some other to handle the post data at server side**.

Comment: Sorry, what is the instance of logData? or it just a simple object?

Comment: @Shiyou Just a simple Object. you can change it to anything you want

Comment: Also, what I want is post file. However, your content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded which cannot do what I want.

Comment: @Shiyou try application/octet-stream

Comment: Sorry, it cannot work. It gives me **500 (Internal Server Error)**. And I check the request, the payload is `[object Object]`

Comment: @Shiyou can you post full code. all you need is upload a file to server?

Comment: This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/L3bvpj1q/   . Yes, i want to use AJAX to upload file